# API call seems to be going through and collecting data but the data does not show in my custom tableview cell

Tags: swift, api, swift3, tableview

I'm making an API call which seems to be going through and collecting data (used print and breakpoints) but seem to still have trouble with my data not showing up in my custom cell. Can someone please take a look and help me out?

Here is my TableView Controller:

```
    var fightersArray: [UFCFighter]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchFighter { (_) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fightersArray?.count ?? 0
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "fighterCell", for: indexPath) as? UFCFighterTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

        cell.fighter = fightersArray?[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func fetchFighter(completion: @escaping ([UFCFighter]?) -> Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://ufc-data-api.ufc.com/api/v1/us/fighters") else { return }
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                completion(nil)
            } else {

                do {

                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)

                    for dictionary in json as! [[String: Any]] {

                        let fighters = UFCFighter()
                        fighters.firstName = dictionary["first_name"] as? String
                        fighters.lastName = dictionary["last_name"] as? String
                        fighters.weightClass = dictionary["weight_class"] as? String
                        fighters.wins = dictionary["wins"] as? Int
                        fighters.losses = dictionary["losses"] as? Int
                        fighters.imageURL = dictionary["thumbnail"] as? String
                        self.fightersArray?.append(fighters)
                        completion(self.fightersArray)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                        print(fighters)
                    }

                } catch {

                    print("error in JSONSerialization")
                }
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Here is my custom cell:

```
    var fighter: UFCFighter? {
        didSet {
            self.nameLabel.text = self.fighter?.fullName
            self.weightClassLabel.text = self.fighter?.weightClass
            self.recordLabel.text = "Wins: \(String(describing: self.fighter?.wins)) - Losses: \(String(describing: self.fighter?.losses))"
            self.setupThumbnailImage()
        }
    }

    func setupThumbnailImage() {
        if let thumbnailImageURL = fighter?.imageURL {
            guard let url = URL(string: thumbnailImageURL) else { return }
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.fighterImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                }
            })
            task.resume()
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var fighterImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var weightClassLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var recordLabel: UILabel!
}
```

Hopefully it's not a dumb question as I'm trying to improve my API skills.

Comment: Have you get any response from API? or set breakpoint after append data into "self.fightersArray?.append(fighters)" and check append or not?

Comment: are you registering `UFCFighterTableViewCell ` as "fighterCell"? It is not in the code provided, and would cause your tableView to just return plain `UITableViewCell`

Comment: HI have got my point your string into somewhere and accessing is in without logic respond me if you have any doubts, cell.nameLabel.text = fightersArray?[indexPath.row]. firstName

Comment: Yes, "fighterCell" was the first thing I verified as it's happened to me before. @TristanBurnside ... BrijeshShiroya I thought values were being appended but they were not b/c as Bacon mentioned, I didn't give the fightersArray a default value of an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your  `var fightersArray: [UFCFighter]?` is nil at the point you are appending it, you need to instantiate the array first before you can do that.

For example, you can change it to  `var fightersArray: [UFCFighter] = []` an it will work. By setting a default value (an empty array) it's not logical to keep it as an optional so I removed the `?`.

Or don't use append but set the fighersArray directly with your fetched data:
`self.fightersArray = fighters`

Comment: That did the trick! I don't know how I didn't catch that, but thanks for your help.